# Vim format specified range

Tags: vim, formatting

I'm curious if there is an option for formatting (ie making lines have similar length) a range.

I have the following comment, and I would like to format the two lines in the middle

```
//TODO:
//a)if only the frame table uses these, then move the content in the frame table source
//file
//b)otherwise, change the names of the functions
```

If I type `gqip`, it will reformat the whole commented section.

I want to use a command of the form:

```
:.,.+1ALLIGN_COMMAND
```

An equivalent one, without using ex would be even better.

So far, I couldn't find any solution in the manual or on the web.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a motion that goes over the range you want, you can use `gq{motion}`. In this case, if you put your cursor on the second line, you can use `gqj`.

More generally, though, you can specify an arbitrary range using visual mode, and then press `gq` to format the selected text.

Answer (score 2):

You can also visually select a range and the apply the required command.